Not able to see plugin "Relay for Android Studio" in Android Studio
I want to install plugin "Relay for Android Studio" to import Figma design. But in my plugins tab I can't see this plugin.
Android Studio version 2023.2.1 (Iguana).
Installed Plugin
Marketplace Plugin
I tried restarting android studio and checking for updates but I am on latest version.

Well the thing is that Relay isnt compatible with the version of your Android Studio.
Check it out:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/19721-relay-for-android-studio
The last compatible versions are: Android Studio — Flamingo | 2022.2.1 — Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 2

Will this plugin come in upcoming versions? Or is there any way to downgrade my Android Studio?

Downgrade your Studio for now rather than waiting for plugin to arrive. Upgrade to latest version when it’s finally compatible with them.

Can you please tell me how to downgrade? I didn't find previous versions for MacOS

Best and maybe only way to downgarde irrespective of any OS is to re-download the desired version and delete the current one.

But on the official download page of Android Studio there is no link to download previous versions. Can you tell me from where can I download it?

Here you go: https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

November 2024, and it's not available on the latest version of Android Studio. The Jetbrains marketplace website gives the following message:
"Not compatible with the version of your running IDE (Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1 Patch 1)". There are a number of reviews where others have tried different versions of Android after Flamingo, but they are still not compatible. It's frustrating because Android Developers website prerequisite states "You have installed Android Studio 2022.2.1 Flamingo or later".
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/19721-relay-for-android-studio/versions/stable
